# Is there anyway to connect external credit card reader and use it in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I want to develop an app that will take the credit card data from the external credit card reader and will use it to talk with the credit company,
but I can't find any info about connecting a credit card reader to a flutter app.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access external devices using flutter but it can be done using native plugins and method channels. you need to search for how to do it in android or ios and then implement it in each platform's project and then connect it to your dart code using a method channel.